# Windows 7 wireless icon says “ internet access” but still no connection

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

Recently my windows 7 Home premium desktop will not reconnect to a wireless network when it comes out of sleep or when I restart. YET, the system tray says it has internet access as too does the Network Manager. So, I ping an external site, and nope - no connection. I try to disconnect and reconnect, I try to do an ipconfig /release then /renew. I try to reboot the router, and also unplug the router. Also I have deleted and reinstalled the wireless adapter drivers.

I have done a full virus scan with McCafee. Nothing produces a result.

In desperation I have even tried reinstalling windows.

Additionally, if you try to open Firefox it will not open either.

EVENTUALLY after say, 5 mins or so, FF opens and a connection is available.

Any ideas of stuff I can try ??

Many thanks !

Answer (score 1):

```
Access to your router via web:
usually http://192.168.0.0 or http://192.168.1.1
```

and check if you have WAN connectivity (usually "Diagnostics").

---

You should also check if your DNS Server is working properly:

```
ping 173.194.41.2 (an Google ip address)
```

instead of ping dns direction

---

You can also execute "**route print**" command in Windows to check if the route table is OK:

```
In IPv4 route table look for network destination 0.0.0.0, and make sure your gateway is the router IP
```

---

Pd: I do not doubt that you will forgive my poor English

Comment: I've got WAN connectivity as other computers in the house can access the net. Just not this one.